# Prototype method not being overriden

Tags: javascript

Why isn't `foo` logged in the console? I assumed that the `foo` base method would be overridden by the child. Why isn't that the case?

```
function parent(){ }
parent.prototype.foo = function(){ 
    console.log('foobar');
};

function child(){ }
child.prototype.foo = function(){ 
    console.log('foo');
};

child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
child.prototype.constructor = child;

console.log(new child().foo()); // foobar
```

Comment: The order matters. You should do child.prototype.foo = function(){ 
    console.log('foo');
}; after Object.create(parent.prototype);.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype)
```

you replace the object on which you previously added a `foo` property.

Just change the order to set the `foo` value later:

```
function parent(){ }
parent.prototype.foo = function(){ 
    console.log('foobar');
};

function child(){ }
child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
child.prototype.foo = function(){ 
    console.log('foo');
};
child.prototype.constructor = child;

console.log(new child().foo()); // foo
```

Comment: Hopefully [ES2015 brings a clearer syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#classes), making class extension easier to write and read.

Comment: Some syntax sugar never hurts :)